# Updating Database Table via Entity Framework Model Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm updating a Product table in db via an object of EF Model class by this code:

```html
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CONFIRM_PRODUCT_EDIT(ADD_PRODUCT_MODEL model) {
    PRODUCT product = db.PRODUCTs.Find(model.PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID);
    product = model.PRODUCT;

    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("ecommerce_products_show");
}
```

Whole code executes smoothly but it doesn't update data in database. 
Am I missing something to get the job done?

Comment: It doesn't work like that,  you have to reset each property of the product to that of the model.

Comment: You only set another reference to product variable (different object), but original product was not change. You can call controller method UpdateModel or set each property manually to modify original product.

Comment: While Debugging it shows me each property updated in product object before db.savechanges(). But back in database it's not updating.

Comment: That's because 'product' is now pointing to the PRODUCT passed into the method, and it is not the instance you got from the database. as zaitsman and Jupin said, you need to update each of the properties on product one by one, not just replace it as you're doing.